# JSON: Creating an array node VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I'm new to this. And I hope someone can help me figure out how to do this
So I have this import on my vb file

```
Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization"
```

Sure I can print JSONObjects however what I want is to print the objects with an array node.

```
Dim arr As New List(Of arr)()
arr.Add(New arr With{.arrId = 0, .arrName = "XXX"})
arr.Add(New arr With{.arrId = 1, .arrName = "YYY"})
```

If I serialize it, it will print this:

```
[{"arrId" : 0, "arrName" : "XXX"},{"arrId" : 1, "arrName" : "YYY"}]
```

But what I want is something that can specify those objects like the word "arrs" e.g.

```
["arrs":{"arrId" : 0, "arrName" : "XXX"},{"arrId" : 1, "arrName" : "YYY"}]
```

Any idea on how I can add "arrs" (list) inside this serialized array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid:

`["arrs":{"arrId" : 0, "arrName" : "XXX"},{"arrId" : 1, "arrName" : "YYY"}]`

- Your first item in the array is:
  `"arrs":{"arrId" : 0, "arrName" : "XXX"}`
- which should be
  `{"arrs":{"arrId" : 0, "arrName" : "XXX"}}`
- and the 2nd item would be
  `{"arrId" : 1, "arrName" : "YYY"}`

Though i don't think that's what you want/intended...

---

Disclaimer: My vb is rusty so improve as needed.

You'll need to "encapsulate" it within another object:

```
Class Container
        Public arrs As List(Of arr)
End Class

Class Child
        Public arrId As Integer
        Public arrName As String
End Class
```

So you can do something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arr As New List(Of Child)()
    arr.Add(New Child With {.arrId = 0, .arrName = "XXX"})
    arr.Add(New Child With {.arrId = 1, .arrName = "YYY"})

    'Object
    Dim foo As New Container With {.arrs = arr}

    'Array
    Dim bar As New List(Of Container)()
    bar.Add(New Container With {.arrs = arr})

    Console.WriteLine("foo serialized:  " + New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(foo))
    Console.WriteLine("bar serialized:  " + New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(bar))
End Sub
```

Which results in:

```
foo serialized:  {"arrs":[{"arrId":0,"arrName":"XXX"},{"arrId":1,"arrName":"YYY"}]}
bar serialized:  [{"arrs":[{"arrId":0,"arrName":"XXX"},{"arrId":1,"arrName":"YYY"}]}]
```

Hth...

Comment: the foo one is the one I need. :D Thank you so much sir!